# How to bundle manually lazy loaded modules with angular4 and webpack ngtools/webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, aot

I have multiple modules in app . i made few of modules are lazy loaded manually as follows

```
 this.moduleLoader.load('Infor.MinglePortal/tsScripts/usersettings/usersettings.module#UserSettingsModule')
        .then((moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
            const vcRef = this.vcRef;
            const ngModuleRef = moduleFactory.create(vcRef.parentInjector);
            const comp = ngModuleRef.injector.get(LazyLoadConfig).component;
            const compFactory = ngModuleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(comp);
            this.compRef = vcRef.createComponent(compFactory, 0, ngModuleRef.injector);
            let info = {
                componentRef: this.compRef,
                factory: compFactory,
                moduleRef: ngModuleRef
            };


        });
```

I am not able to bundle this with webpack3 , ngtools/webpack and aot.

here is my tsconfig and webpack.config.js

```
enter code{
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "es2015",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "target": "es5",
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "mapRoot": "",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "lib": [
    "es2015",
    "dom"
  ],
  "outDir": "lib",
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "baseUrl": ".",


},
"exclude":["./Abc.AbcPortal/tsScripts/abc-aot.ts", "./build/*", "./dist/*","node_modules"],
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "debug": true,
  "entryModule":"./Infor.AbcPortal/tsScripts/abc/abc.module#abcModule"
}
```

}

webpack.config.js

```
const ngToolsWebpack = require("@ngtools/webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
  },
  node: {
    net: "empty",
    tls: "empty"
  },
  entry: "./abc.abcPortal/tsScripts/main.ts",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./build/"),
    publicPath: "/build/",
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new ngToolsWebpack.AotPlugin({
      tsConfigPath: "./tsconfig-web3.json"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "raw-loader" },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: "raw-loader" },
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: ["@ngtools/webpack"] }
    ]
  }
```

My Problem is i am unable to load the lazy loaded modules with webpack + aot + ngtools/webpack .

I am getting the following error when i load lazy loaded module.

main.bundle.js:2387 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'abc.MinglePortal/tsScripts/usersettings/usersettings.module.ngfactory'.
Error: Cannot find module 'abc.MinglePortal/tsScripts/usersettings/usersettings.module.ngfactory'.

Please help me out.